# Storing data from html form to excel tabel?

Tags: javascript, php, excel, html

Is there any way to store data that visitors enter in website **form** (name, email, address etc..) to excel database.

So if my visitor enter that information, they instantly store to excel database.

Please send me some tutorials or something like that so I can read and do it.
I can use PHP or JavaScript, it doesn't matter I just want to know how to do that.

Comment: An "excel database"?

Comment: Ripping stuff of the net is easy:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ISmZVK0GGFU&list=PL6OYc4rwKjcOu3UL7LYpvO_S2waYO-hVU

Comment: Questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam. Instead, describe the problem and what has been done so far to solve it.

Comment: @JonathanLam . yes, an excel database

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [PHPExcel](https://phpexcel.codeplex.com/) library to Read, Write and Create Excel documents in PHP.

This library provides  a set of classes for the PHP programming language, which allow you to write to and read from different spreadsheet file formats.

Library URL: https://phpexcel.codeplex.com/